# How to prevent radial gradient applied to a circle go out of svg polygon?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have `svg polygon` created dynamically of any shape and size.  In that I have an `svg circle` which has gradient applied.
How to prevent the gradient go out of the polygon?

As polygon cannot have child elements.
That svg circle can have any position. It may or may not be in the centre of the shape.

I have tried applying the gradient to polygon directly but then it gets applied to the whole polygon which I do not want. Because there can be many circles in the same polygon.

Comment: Pleas add a [mcve] to your question, otherwise it's rather hard to follow.

Comment: Show us your code and what you've tried.

Comment: Sounds like you need some form of *clipping* - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/clip-path.html

Comment: Yes i got the ans. I have used clipping. Thank you for your answers.